# Epsilon delta is super redundant, isn't it?

Tags: limits, derivatives, epsilon-delta

I have a very different question.

I was looking into $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit. I actually understand the idea, but what I'm wondering is why it was necessary to come up with such an idea in the first place.

Looking at functions, such as $x+1$ , it's super clear that when x approaches to 2, value of $f(x)$ approaches to 3. We could just leave it like that because to me, it already feels a proof that we can plug in 2 and get the value. It definitely means that if I had plugged in 2.0001, i would get a little bigger value, but still close to 2.

I'm just looking at the proof of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ and still can't make myself happy why the definition is even necessary.  in one of the books, I read:

> The intuitive definition of a limit given in Section 2.2 is inadequate
> for some purposes because such phrases as “ is close to 2” and “ gets
> closer and closer to L” are vague.

Well to me, $\epsilon-\delta$ ends up being vague. Maybe I don't see how it's a proof and thats why my confusion. So whatever range I give you $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, you should be able to give me the range near $a$, such as $|x-a| < \delta$. So what if I can give you that ? It seems such a redundant proof to me.

Would appreciate your thoughts !

Comment: "Epsilon delta is super redundant, isn't it?"  No, it really isn't.  The notion of limit which you have come up with is that of "sequential limits".  In the real numbers, $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ limits are equivalent to sequential limits, but this is not necessarily true in more general spaces.

Comment: Reads more like a rant than a question.  Do you not believe that the definition matches intuition?  Do you have an example of this to help us?  Or do you not understand the definition?  Look at some "wilder" examples of functions where your intuition is not a clear guide to understand the importance and effectiveness of this definition.

Comment: Also, as a counter example to your notion of "just plugging in" a number to a function", what is $\lim_{x\to 0} x \sin(1/x)$?  This function is not define at $0$, so there is no way to "plug in" zero.  Same with $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x) /x$.  How do you handle these?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does $\epsilon$-$\delta$ explain the idea of 'approach'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071309/how-does-epsilon-delta-explain-the-idea-of-approach)

Comment: ^closest dupe target I could find.

Comment: well, for limit approach zero cases, I might understand why it could be needed, but not for any other limit values and functions that don't have in the denominator a variable

Comment: @Chemistry Define a function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational, and} \\
1/q & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x = p/q$ in lowest terms.}\end{cases}$$
What is $\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}} f(x)$?  What about $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)$?

Comment: How do you define "approaches" or "near"?

Comment: You are being given extremely simple examples, so that you can learn how to use the epsilon-delta apparatus with fewer distractions. That's what text books do. It's like people don't learn how to drive starting on the freeway, they start in a parking lot. And this question is roughly equivalent to "why do I need to learn about my turn signals? I'm only going 5 mph and I'm the only one here in this lot.".

Comment: You might as well be asking why we should prove something like $1+2+3+4+\ldots$ goes off to $\infty$ when we can intuitively see that adding bigger and bigger numbers results in bigger and bigger numbers. If we didn't have precise definitions/theorems/axioms/etc., then what's the point of math?

Comment: Hmmm.... *Definition: $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$ means that its super clear that when $x$ approaches $a$, the value of $f(x)$ approaches $f(a)$*... talk about vague...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question

> why it was necessary to come up with such an idea in the first place.

through the pseudo-historical lens (i.e some of the stuff I say may not be 100% historically accurate, so take this my own vague retelling of history).

You're making argument with pretty simple examples. For these, you should think of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition as a "test-case", i.e does it give you the answer you expect or not (more precisely, does the answer you expect satisfy the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ condition). Note that for centuries, people were perfectly happy to get by without $\epsilon$-$\delta$, and everyone knew what they were roughly talking about.

But, as time passed, the definition of *function* itself has evolved from something along the lines of "a formula" (essentially a quotient of two analytic functions (actually not even that general perhaps)) into something extremely general. With the broader definition of function, people started to ask whether it is possible to extend the notion of limit for such functions as well. In some cases, the answers were still easy to work out, whereas in other cases, not so much. Furthermore, around the 1700-1800s, people were very interested in dealing with infinite series and infinite products, trying to push the boundaries of what had already been established. People then realized that with the crazier things they were considering (including things like Fourier series, swapping series and derivatives and integrals etc) they couldn't really get correct answers, or even if they did, someone else would get other answers and so on. All of this boiled down to not having a precise enough definition for limits, and by extension, precise theorems guaranteeing the validity of the manipulations they were doing. So one day they were like enough is enough, and people (eg Cauchy and Weierstrass) formulated the precise definition. Btw, just because this super precise definition was available, it didn't mean people leapt in joy, there was (very understandably) a considerable resistance to accepting it due to its terse nature. But soon everyone started to realize its necessity in dealing with the problems they had in mind.

What you're studying now is the product of centuries' worth of distillation of a core idea, and you're studying it "top-down", which is why you probably don't appreciate its importance. But, rest assured, this definition gave people the confidence that what they were doing was actually right (because without a precise definition, you cannot have a precise theorem).

---

Now, I should mention that $\epsilon$-$\delta$ does not help us "calculate" limits (though sometimes it can easily tell us when something is *not* the limit, in the sense that it is easy to verify that a given number $\lambda$ does not satisfy the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$). In fact, in much of modern math, we rarely use the definition to compute things! We use the (very precise, and sometimes, extremely difficult) definitions in order to *prove* a whole variety of theorems. In the case of limits, these involve things like sum, product, quotient (modulo division by zero) rules, and most importantly, composition, and other things like L'Hopital's rule, FTC etc etc. It is only with these theorems that in practice we compute anything.

Comment: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/how-math-works

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Do we use this epsilon-delta approach to find limit or it's just only a way to prove whether our "alredy found limit" is correct or not ? if it can help us find the limit, would appreciate where I can find it because all textbooks only show its usage in proving the derived limit is accurate

Comment: @XanderHenderson lmao yea. last semester I had students who couldn't fully **understand** the limit definition after the end of the semester even though their mark were decent. I told them essentially this

Comment: Again, @Chemistry, the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition neither "helps us to find a limit" nor "prove that a derived limit is accurate".  It is the *definition* of a limit.  If you want to "prove that a derived limit is accurate", you first have to have a definition of what a limit **is**.  Absent *some* definition, it doesn't make sense to talk about either "finding" a limit, nor "verifying" a limit.

Comment: @Chemistry I just elaborated on that in my recently edited final paragraph.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I put a link to that comic on the front page of every syllabus I write.  It helps, I think, to tell students that our knowledge was hard won, even if we distill it down to a single semester for the purposes of finishing a degree. :D

Comment: @Chemistry: Even though you might have an intuitive idea of what a limit is, the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition offers a precise, watertight, definition of a limit. The necessity of such a precise definition is elaborated in peek-a-boo's answer. This definition is not really useful for computation of limits – indeed, proving that a function approaches some limit using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition **directly** is often a very cumbersome process.

Comment: @peek-a-boo yeah, i finished university 5 years ago which means i learned calculus  8years ago and my mark was B+ which is funny, but I love what one of the physicists said one day: "lots of geniuses physicists really study lots of things super fast, but after some time, they come back to beginner topics that they learned in the first year and start to ask: what "mass" is for example". Not that I don't emphasize that I'm a genius. infinitely far from it

Comment: Yes, I understand now that it's a definition. Though, what I was asking is in practice, when do I use it ? let's say someone comes to me and tells me: find the limit of this function - when would I need to use this definition in practice ? when would my intuitive understanding not be enough ? in other words, a great example of why people decided to come up with this definition in the past would be super helpful. What was it that they were lacking before this defintion ? while @peek-a-boo certainly explained the history, practical example of usefulness of this definition would be amazing

Comment: @Chemistry: Consider the function $f(x)$, defined for $0<x<1$, which equals $0$ when $x$ is irrational, and $f(x)=1/q$ if $x=p/q$ (in lowest terms). I don't find it particularly intuitive that for all $a\in(0,1)$, the function $f$ approaches $0$ near $a$. What about you?

Comment: @Chemistry oh I should have also mentioned that sometimes, the definitions we come up with are also motivated by what theorems we'd like to be able to prove, because often what happens is we have some result that appears to be true and then we "work backwards" and try to come up with a definitions/bunch of definitions which makes the resulting theory work out. For limits, the fact that $\epsilon$-$\delta$ keeps the many "basic rules" (linearity, products, quotients, compositions) is a plus.

Comment: and for an examples besides the usual ones ($x\sin(1/x)$ and various L-Hopital's-ish stuff) think about an integral $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ (let's say you already defined an integral somehow). We know atleast heuristically that the fundamental theorem of calculus holds $F'(x)=f(x)$. How do we prove it? What are the precise assumptions on $f$ that we need/are sufficient to guarantee this equality? These are all questions one can ask. The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ then allows us to actually prove/disprove it with a given set of assumptions. Also, see Thomae's function above.

Comment: @Joe and epsilon-delta helps you make sure it's 0 ? how exactly

Comment: @Chemistry: This example is taken from Spivak's *Calculus*. I will link a screenshot of his argument, using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$, that this is true. It's not particularly easy reading – I would get out a pen and paper and try and follow his argument carefully. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HyMQ.jpg

Comment: Yes, found a good youtube video as well. I guess I will follow it. Thanks everyone. I will read again everything tomorrow and if anything, I will ask a better question.

Comment: "and epsilon-delta helps you make sure it's 0 ? how exactly"  Once again, the epsilon-delta definition is not there to "help" you justify that the limit is zero.  It is there to explain what a limit **is**.  Absent the epsilon-delta definition, how can you say *anything* about what happens to $f(x)$ as $x$ "approaches" $a$ for any given $a \in (0,1)$ (in Joe's example)?  What does "approaches" even mean?  Without a definition, what are we even talking about?

Answer (score 9):

I completely sympathise with the feeling that using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ to prove that $$\lim_{x\to2}x+1=3$$is overkill somehow. However, there are good reasons to do this. Here are two:

- Many times $\epsilon$-$\delta$ is not overkill, and by then you need to know how to use it. Using it in examples that are so simple you can see the moving parts is how you learn. Go down the kid's slope a few times to learn turning and braking before you try the world cup downhill piste, if you will.
- "It already feels like proof that we can plug in $2$ and get a value" yes, but ultimately the true justification for this is still $\epsilon$-$\delta$.

Any calculus student with a keen mind will intuitively understand what limits are supposed to be. And they will be able to apply this intuitive understanding to most introductory examples. However, when things become more complicated, in order to actually make sure that everyone agrees *exactly* on what a limit is, we need to nail down a rigorous definition. It is also necessary to have a definition to work with if you're ever going to do actual calculations, rather than just looking at a problem and intuit a likely solution.

The hope is, of course, that the rigorous definition yields results that agree with most people's intuitions, and that it is relatively easy to use in calculations. And the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition does this. Which is why it has stood the test of time and is still used centuries after its conception.

The idea of this exercise is to help you understand the inner workings of $\epsilon$-$\delta$, and to convince you that it does yield the results it should. This exercise is *not* made to demonstrate the power of $\epsilon$-$\delta$. That comes later.

Comment: Maybe, the places where it could be useful is when x approaches zero and we got x in the denominator. In all other cases, it seems redundant. do you agree ?

Comment: @Chemistry That's the _first_ place where it starts to be useful. There are _so_ many others, as you will discover in the months and years to come.

Comment: @Chemistry What's $$\lim_{x\to 1} (\log x)(\log(\log x))?$$  What's $$\lim_{x\to 0} (\cos x)^{\cot x}?$$

Comment: @MJD the problem is in the textbooks, I see that - is used to prove that limit is the answer, so - doesn't help us find the limit, but helps us prove it ?

Comment: The limit is **defined** in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$.  Epsilons and deltas don't help us "find" a limit, nor "prove" that a limit is one thing or another.  They are a fundamental part of the *definition* of a limit.  At a foundational level, you cannot discuss a limit without first talking about epsilons and deltas (or choosing an entirely different, but equally rigorous approach to limits, e.g. quantifying over all sequences, or taking Abraham Robinson's infinitesimal approach).

Comment: @Chemistry If you read the exact phrasing, you will note that the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition is based on the idea that you already have a "candidate" limit, and the definition tells you what's required in order to actually call it a limit. So yes, often you will guess what the limit is through other means, and then determine whether it is truly the limit with $\epsilon$-$\delta$. Some times you use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ calculations themselves to find the candidate limit as well, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @MJD commented how I find the limit of lim→0(cos)^(cotx) and I said that epsilon delta doesn't help us find the limit. If it does help us, I'd love to ask you where I find an article that explains it, otherwise, the way is we figure out the limit by ourselves and then prove it.

Comment: @Chemistry Okay, so what *is* $\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(x)^{\cot(x)}$?

Comment: @Chemistry: the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition allows you to prove limit theorems which are then used to evaluate limits. So in an indirect way the definition is used to evaluate limits. Compare this with definition of area and the formulas for areas of various shapes which are actually used to evaluate areas.

Comment: @Chemistry: most calculus textbooks written for beginners hide the details which lead from definition of limit to limit theorems and then to evaluation of a limit.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found an application for ε−δ when dealing with math brain teasers (which is probably overkill). Take the following question that's a glorified riddle:

> Consider the sum:
>
> > 1/2 ± 1/4 ± 1/8 ± 1/16 ± ...

> Depending on the choice of +'s and -'s, does this family of sums have a sum that converges to **every** real number between 0 and 1?

The answer is *yes*, and that can be loosely found by *epsilon-delta*-ing your way to the answer (it's like starting at 1/2 and taking steps left and right of that on the number line).

(and this'll answer your original question best) ε-δ is a helpful way to convert the intuition of limits into proof more rigorously which has been the path of the mathematician for centuries.